# Beginner rock, paper, scissor program in java code

Tags: java

I'm working on a java program which calls rock, paper, scissor. And I have an issue with the while loop when I tried to run it, it didn't stop when I expected it too. I'm new to java code and my professor said that I can't use break; and static method is for later use not now. So, some advice base on my code structures will be awesome. Thanks

I have tried many different way to make it running, first I used a for loop but then realized that it only run a certain amount of time not just stop when some one reach the amount of winning rounds that needed. So, I switched to while loop and it didn't work either because it ignored the condition inside and keep running the program. (M

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Rock {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      //Variables
      int win;
      int man;
      int count =0;

      int gameHuman =0;
      int gameComp =0;
      //Scanner object
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


      System.out.println("Welcome to my game of Rock, Paper, Scissors!");

      System.out.println("How many winning rounds are needed for victory? : ");
      win = input.nextInt(); //User input

      //loop
      while(gameHuman <=win || gameComp <=win) {                       
         int computer = (int)(Math.random()*3);
         System.out.print("Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: ");
         man= input.nextInt();
         System.out.println();

         if(man == 0 && computer == 0) {
            System.out.println("Human: Rock       " + "Computer: Rock");
            System.out.println("Draw, try again.");
            count++;
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();
         }
         else if(man == 0 && computer == 1) {
            System.out.println("Human: Rock     " + "Computer: Paper");
            System.out.println("Computer win.");
            count++;
            gameComp++;            
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();           
         }
         else if(man == 0 && computer == 2) {
            System.out.println("Human: Rock    " + "Computer: Scissor");
            System.out.println("Human win.");
            count++;
            gameHuman++;
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();
         }   
         if(man == 1 && computer == 0) {
            System.out.println("Human: Paper       " + "Computer: Rock");
            System.out.println("Human win.");
            count++;
            gameHuman++;
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();
         }
         else if(man == 1 && computer == 1) {
            System.out.println("Human: Paper     " + "Computer: Paper");
            System.out.println("Draw, try again.");
            count++;
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();
         }
         else if(man == 1 && computer == 2) {
            System.out.println("Human: Paper    " + "Computer: Scissor");
            System.out.println("Computer win.");
            count++;
            gameComp++;
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();
         }   
         if(man == 2 && computer == 0) {
            System.out.println("Human: Scissor       " + "Computer: Rock");
            System.out.println("Computer win.");
            count++;
            gameComp++;
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();
         }
         else if(man == 2 && computer == 1) {
            System.out.println("Human: Scissor     " + "Computer: Paper");
            System.out.println("Human win.");
            count++;
            gameHuman++;
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();
         }
         else if(man == 2 && computer == 2) {
            System.out.println("Human: Scissor    " + "Computer: Scissor");
            System.out.println("Draw, try again.");
            count++;
            System.out.println("Total score:  Human " + gameHuman + "  Computer: " + gameComp); 
            System.out.println();
         }                       
      } 

      System.out.println(count);
      System.out.println(gameComp +" " + gameHuman);
   }//end main
}//end class   

//Run the game
Welcome to my game of Rock, Paper, Scissors!
How many winning rounds are needed for victory? : 
3
Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock     Computer: Paper
Computer win.
Total score:  Human 0  Computer: 1

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock    Computer: Scissor
Human win.
Total score:  Human 1  Computer: 1

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock       Computer: Rock
Draw, try again.
Total score:  Human 1  Computer: 1

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock     Computer: Paper
Computer win.
Total score:  Human 1  Computer: 2

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock       Computer: Rock
Draw, try again.
Total score:  Human 1  Computer: 2

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock     Computer: Paper
Computer win.
Total score:  Human 1  Computer: 3

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock    Computer: Scissor
Human win.
Total score:  Human 2  Computer: 3

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock       Computer: Rock
Draw, try again.
Total score:  Human 2  Computer: 3

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock       Computer: Rock
Draw, try again.
Total score:  Human 2  Computer: 3

Enter 0=rock, 1=paper, 2=scissors: 0

Human: Rock     Computer: Paper
Computer win.
Total score:  Human 2  Computer: 4
```

I expect it to stop when either human or computer reach the amount of wins that user input in which is 3.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the 3 with the user intput "win"

Also remove the equal so when any player gets to the win condition the game ends.

and use && instead of ||

```
win = input.nextInt(); //User input

while(gameHuman < win && gameComp < win) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. It works ! I was confusing on && with || because I thought if 1 condition is match it gonna stop the loop.